# Explicit webcam binding with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webcam

Whenever I start Firefox (95.0.2) my JavaScript in Chrome loses connection to the webcam. When I end Firefox and reload/refresh my program in Chrome, the webcam stream is visible again.

The JavaScript connects via:

```
stream   =   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({  
               video : true
             , audio : true })
```

Is there a possibility to manually bind the webcam to the last run JavaScript, so I click F5 in any browser and then the webcam is bound to this browser until I refresh the site within a different browser?